# Can not parse the string to Exact DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datetime

I have DateTime in string format.
`2013-03-05T08:28:18+0000`.

I need output like :- `Mar 5, 2013 8:28:18 PM`

I am trying to parse to DateTime Format.

```
string givenDate="2013-03-05T08:28:18+0000";

DateTime parsedDate= DateTime.Parse(givenDate);

string  output= parsedDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");

Console.WriteLine("OutPut is==>"+output);
```

But my out is :-`Mar 5, 2013 01:58:18 PM`

Here time is getting changed. My expected output is -:-`Mar 5, 2013 8:28:18 PM`

I have try like this also.

```
 parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-03-05T08:28:18+0000", "MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", new CultureInfo("tr-TR"));
```

But here I am getting error:- `Value does not fall within the expected range.`

I have try like this also:-

```
parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-03-05T08:28:18+0000", "MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

and this

```
parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-03-05T08:28:18+0000", "MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Both are showing this error:- `FormatException`

Please help to convert the DateTime as what I need.

Comment: Pattern string you're using has nothing in common with your input format or desired result string... That's not gonna work.

Comment: Hi @MarcinJuraszek. Thanks for your reply. Please give me any idea to resolve this problem.

Comment: Read this MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx and prepare correct formats for both parsing and `ToString` call. You should be able to do it quite easily. This way you'll learn much more than just by copy/pasting an answer I could provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
string givenDate = ("2013-03-05T08:28:18+0000");
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(givenDate, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string ouputDate = d.ToUniversalTime().ToString("MMM d, yyyy h:m:s tt",  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thank you @ Hiral Nayak.. It's Working..!! :-) May I know what actually happen here?

Answer (score 1):

```
    //First, your entry does not include AM or PM.
    //Therefore it is considered a time format 24H
    string inputDate="2013-03-05T08:28:18+0000";
    //We indicate culture, although in this step is not necessary.
    DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(inputDate,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    //Your date, contains the modifier +0000, indicating a time zone
    //We must become universal time, or local time is displayed
    //If you only want 1 digit for the hours, minutes, seconds, when their value < 10, we use a single symbol format
    // 01:02:03 ->1:2:3 using h:m:s -> 01:02:03 using hh:mm:ss
    //We use invariant culture, or we want to display the data
    string ouputDate = d.ToUniversalTime().ToString("MMM d, yyyy h:m:s tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    // ouputDate ="Mar 5, 2013 8:28:18 AM"; 
    // Because your date dont include any time zone specifier, if want to convert to DateTime, must specify some
    // or DateTimeKind.Unspecified is used
    //Try this
    Console.WriteLine(ouputDate);
    DateTime d2 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(ouputDate,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),DateTimeKind.Utc);
    Console.WriteLine(d2);
    DateTime d3 = d2.ToLocalTime();
    Console.WriteLine(d3);
    DateTime d4 = d2.ToUniversalTime();
    Console.WriteLine(d4);
//Here d2 is DateTimeKind.Unspecified, the strange result happen in the conversion to string
    d2 = DateTime.Parse(ouputDate,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(d2);
    d3 = d2.ToLocalTime();
    Console.WriteLine(d3);
    d4 = d2.ToUniversalTime();
    Console.WriteLine(d4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first line defines a date/time for Coordinated Universal Time with zero offset (AFAIR the time valid for Greenwich, UK).

Your second line parses this time correctly, however it readjusts the time for your local time offset. It adds 5:30 hours, because you live in the time zone UTC+5:30.

On top your input is an early morning time (08:28), but you expect it to be an evening time (08:28 PM).

That's why line three and four show the "unexpected" result.

You have some options:

- change the input to `"2013-03-05T08:28:18+0530"`
- change the input to `"2013-03-05T08:28:18"`
- readjust the output with `parsedDate = parsedDate.ToUniversalTime();`